# accessing SoundManager 2 across functions

Tags: javascript, flash, soundmanager2

Ok this thing is awesome!  I got SoundManager 2 setup within my .js file and have audio playing on my page.  My only question at the moment, is figuring out how to play audio outside of the soundManager.setup({...}).  For example the following works great...

```
function mSound() {
/*SETUP SOUND MANAGER 2*/
soundManager.setup({
// where to find flash audio SWFs, as needed
url: 'audio/',
onready: function() {
console.log('SM2 is ready to play audio!');

    /*MY SOUND COLLECTIONS*/ 
    soundManager.createSound({
    id: 'myIntro',
    url: 'audio/Indonesia.mp3',
    autoPlay: false,
    volume: 15
    });
    soundManager.play('myIntro');

}
});
}
```

But if I try to place soundManager.play('myIntro'), into another function like...

```
function mIntro() {
 soundManager.play('myIntro');
}
```

...the audio does not play.  Any advice will be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it.  By setting up local variables as parameters for my mSound() function like so...

```
function mSound(id,url,volume) {
this.id = id;
this.url = url;
this.volume = volume;

/*SETUP SOUND MANAGER 2*/
soundManager.setup({
url: 'audio/',
onready: function() {
         //console.log('SM2 is ready to play audio!');
     /*MY SOUND COLLECTIONS*/ 
     soundManager.createSound({
     id: id,
     url: 'audio/'+ url,
     volume: volume
     });
     soundManager.play(id);
     }
}); 
}
```

...I'm now able to do cool stuff like this within other javascript functions and play sound!

```
mSound('myIntro','Indonesia.mp3',5);
```

And you can still still use the soundManager global object properties after you load your custom function.  For example you can pause your track like this later in your code...

```
 soundManager.togglePause('myIntro');
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var sound = soundManager.getSoundById('myIntro');
sound.play();
```

It's working in my project.